# Country Code Picker with phone number input in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I want to create this type of UI in React Native, I am using the "react-native-phone-number-input" library to this.

My code is :

```
   <PhoneInput
     defaultValue = {myText}
     defaultCode ='AE'
     backgroundColor = 'black'
     containerStyle = {styles.phoneNumberViewContatiner}
     textContainerStyle={{ borderRadius : 5, borderWidth : 1 }}
     textInputProps = {{showSoftInputOnFocus: false}}
     onChangeFormattedText={text => {setPhoneNumber(text);}}
   />
```

and  this is my style for the container :

```
phoneNumberViewContatiner : {
    width: '80%',
    height: 65,
    fontSize : 60,
    fontWeight : 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    borderColor : 'grey', 
    borderWidth : 4, 
    borderRadius : 7,
    marginTop : -45
   },
```

I have also tried the following libraries to do this like :

- "@digieggs/rn-country-code-picker'
- "react-native-country-codes-picker"
- "react-native-country-picker-modal"
- "react-phone-input-2"

Can someone help me to achieve this,
and Here I also want that when I click on phone number input box, then it's default keyboard should not be open up, I want to input numbers from my custom keyboard like in the following Image. So please help me in this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you good person, this is the only country code picker that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid using the virtual keyboard then, instead of using an input field you can use a Text component.
I did something similar in a project and used [react-native-country-picker-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-country-picker-modal) for phone input.

CountryPhoneInput Component:

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CountryPicker from "react-native-country-picker-modal";
import Keypad from "./Keypad";

export default function CountryPhoneInput() {
  const [phoneCountryCode, setPhoneCountryCode] = useState("PK");
  const [phoneCountryCallingCode, setPhoneCountryCallingCode] = useState("92");
  const [showPhoneCountryPicker, setShowPhoneCountryPicker] = useState(false);
  const [phoneNo, setPhoneNo] = useState("123123");

  const onPressKeypad = (number) => {
    if (isNaN(number)) {
      switch (number) {
        case "delete":
          setPhoneNo(phoneNo.slice(0, phoneNo.length - 1));
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    } else {
      setPhoneNo(`${phoneNo}${number}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <CountryPicker
          countryCode={phoneCountryCode}
          visible={showPhoneCountryPicker}
          onSelect={(country) => {
            console.log("COUNTERY ==> ", country);
            setPhoneCountryCode(country.cca2);
            setPhoneCountryCallingCode(country.callingCode);
            setShowPhoneCountryPicker(false);
          }}
          withFilter={true}
        />
        <View style={styles.phoneTextContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.phoneCountryCallingCodeText}>
            +{phoneCountryCallingCode}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.phoneNoText}>{phoneNo}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.keypadContainer}>
        <Keypad onPress={(number) => onPressKeypad(number)} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#F0EAD8",
  },
  inputContainer: {
    height: 80,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#808080",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  phoneTextContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    height: "100%",
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 10,
  },
  phoneCountryCallingCodeText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  phoneNoText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  keypadContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Keypad Component:

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

export default function Keypad({ onPress }) {
  const keyPadRows = [
    ["1", "2", "3"],
    ["4", "5", "6"],
    ["7", "8", "9"],
    ["*", "0", "#"],
    ["", "call", "delete"],
  ];

  const onPressButton = (button) => {
    onPress(button);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {keyPadRows.map((row) => (
        <View style={styles.keyPadRow}>
          {row.map((button) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.keypadButton}
              onPress={() => onPressButton(button)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.keypadLabel}>{button}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    padding: 50,
  },
  keyPadRow: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  keypadButton: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: "#AAAAAA",
  },
  keypadLabel: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

Result:
[image]
This is a rough draft that I just made for your case. Obviously, this needs some conditioning and validation but hopefully, this will help you in what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the reply.
I tried this solution,  but it is not providing the output that I want.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on what is your expected output?

Comment: I want the exact same layout I have provided in first image, and when I'm trying to do that then it is providing error for large country code digit.

Comment: I gave you this snippet as an example that you can build upon, I also mentioned the library that I'm using. You can get more details about it in the documentation at [https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal](Github Repo)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in react.js:

```js
export const dialConfig = [
    ['1', ''],
    ['2', 'ABC'],
    ['3', 'DEF'],
    ['4', 'GHI'],
    ['5', 'JKL'],
    ['6', 'MNO'],
    ['7', 'PQRS'],
    ['8', 'TUV'],
    ['9', 'WXYZ'],
    ['*', ''],
    ['0', '#'],
    ['+', ''],
]

const [dialValue, setDialValue] = useAtom(dialValueAtom) // used jatoi for SM

const handleRemoveLastChar = () => {
        setDialValue(prevValue => prevValue.slice(0, prevValue.length - 1))
    }

const handleAppendDialValue = value => {
        setDialValue(prevValue => prevValue + value)
    }
```

```html
<CommonModal
            isOpen={isOpen}
            onClose={onClose}
            size="md"
            modalBodyPadding="0px"
        >
            <Box
                background="steelblue"
                // bg="linear-gradient(135deg, #251285 0%, #3D5AFE 45.42%, #04E7E7 100%)"
                height="43.5rem"
                paddingTop="3rem"
                overflow="hidden"
                borderRadius="5px"
            >
                <NumberDisplay />
                <NumberPad />
                <Box height="60%" overflow="scroll">
                    <ContactList />
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </CommonModal>

const NumberDisplay = () => {
    const { dialValue, handleRemoveLastChar } = useDialValue()
    let showBackspace = null

    if (dialValue?.length) {
        showBackspace = (
            <Box
                as="a"
                position="absolute"
                left="100%"
                marginLeft="-5rem"
                cursor="pointer"
                marginTop="20px"
                onClick={e => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    handleRemoveLastChar()
                }}
            >
                <FaDeleteLeft size={40} />
            </Box>
        )
    }
    return (
        <Box
            background="linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)"
            lineHeight="5rem"
            textAlign="center"
            fontSize="3.2rem"
            position="relative"
        >
            {showBackspace}
            <Text h="75px" margin="0" fontSize="53px" color="cornsilk">
                {dialValue}
            </Text>
        </Box>
    )
}

const NumberPad = () => {
    const { handleAppendDialValue } = useDialValue()

    return (
        <Grid
            templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)"
            mx="auto"
            textAlign="center"
            backgroundColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"
            width="100%"
        >
            {dialConfig.map((config, index) => (
                <Box
                    key={index}
                    color="cornsilk"
                    borderBottom="1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
                    borderRight="1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
                    padding=".5rem"
                    cursor="pointer"
                    flex="1 0 33.3%"
                    _hover={{
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.05)',
                    }}
                    textAlign="center"
                    display="inline-block"
                    onClick={() => {
                        handleAppendDialValue(config[0])
                    }}
                >
                    <Text fontSize="2rem" minH="2.4rem" lineHeight="2.4rem">
                        {config[0]}
                    </Text>
                    <Text fontSize=".8rem" minH="1rem" lineHeight="1rem">
                        {config[1] || '\u200b'}
                    </Text>
                </Box>
            ))}
        </Grid>
    )
}

const ContactList = () => {
    const { data } = useGetContactList()
    const contacts = useFilteredContacts(data)
    const { phoneFormat } = useDialValue()

    return (
        <Box>
            {contacts?.map(contact => {
                const fullName = `${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}`
                return (
                    <Box
                        className={'list-item'}
                        key={contact.id}
                        borderBottom="1px solid #9AA9BB"
                        p="1rem 2rem"
                        display="flex"
                        flexDirection="row"
                        justifyContent="space-between"
                        width="100%"
                        flexWrap="wrap"
                    >
                        <Box
                            className={'person'}
                            display="flex"
                            alignItems="center"
                        >
                            <Image
                                className={'avatar'}
                                src={`https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=random&color=000&name=${fullName}`}
                                alt={fullName}
                                borderRadius="5rem"
                                width="50px"
                                mr="1rem"
                            />
                            <Box>
                                <Text
                                    className={'name'}
                                    color="cornsilk"
                                    fontSize="2rem"
                                >
                                    {fullName}
                                </Text>
                                <Text
                                    className={'phone'}
                                    color="cornsilk"
                                    fontSize="1.4rem"
                                >
                                    {phoneFormat(contact.phone)}
                                </Text>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                        <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
                            <Box marginLeft="7px" cursor="pointer">
                                <Link to={`tel:${contact.phone}`}>
                                    <FiPhone size={25} color="cornsilk" />
                                </Link>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                )
            })}
            {contacts.length === 0 && (
                <Text
                    color="cornsilk"
                    fontSize="2.5rem"
                    mt="2rem"
                    display="flex"
                    justifyContent="center"
                >
                    No contacts found
                </Text>
            )}
        </Box>
    )
}
```